# Im using gmp in C and next prime isnt working? Im trying to generate rsa keys

Tags: c, rsa, gmp

```
mpz_t rand1,rand2;
mpz_init (rand1);
mpz_init (rand2);

mpz_random (rand1,512);
//mpz_random (rand2,512);

mpz_nextprime ( rand2, rand1 );
gmp_printf("random %Zd\n", rand2);
//free the big ints
mpz_clear(rand1);
mpz_clear(rand2);
```

However is i print after random it works but the second i call next prime nothing prints out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the info page:

> -- Function: void mpz_random (mpz_t ROP, mp_size_t MAX_SIZE)
>        Generate a random integer of at most MAX_SIZE limbs.  The generated
>        random number doesn't satisfy any particular requirements of
>        randomness.  Negative random numbers are generated when MAX_SIZE
>        is negative.
>
> This function is obsolete.  Use `mpz_urandomb' or`mpz_urandomm'
>        instead.

You're creating a random(ish) integer with 512 limbs, that's 16384 bits if a limb is 32 bits, or 32768 bits if a limb is 64 bits. Primes in that range are sparse, so GMP will take a while to find one.

Presumably you intended to find a prime of 512 bits?

Comment: That depends, are you on a 64-bit system or 32? That would be either 8 or 16 limbs. I apologise for the original snark, had a bad moment.

Comment: @Thefirstkilla But, the random integer generated by `mpz_random` can be shorter than the specified number of limbs, so you should better specify one limb more and check whether it's large enough but not too large. If not, create a new random integer and check again.

Comment: 32 bit thanks i tried to use the urandomb but the numbers were too small

Comment: mpz_urandomb(rand_Num,r_state,14); returned small numbers

Comment: I would recommend creating a random integer in the range `0` to `2^511-1` with `urandomb` (so the mp_bitcnt_t parameter should be 511), and add that to `2^511` to get a 512-bit random integer.

Comment: http://gmplib.org/manual/Nomenclature-and-Types.html found the man page thanks for everything

Comment: great ok well got it trying it now

Comment: Finally i Can move on got it Dan thanks for the help Faster response than my teacher